# Are there any pen-and-paper RPGs based on the writings of Ray Bradbury?

Tags: game-recommendation

As the title says:

Are there any PnP RPGs out there that are based on the unforgettable works of **Ray Bradbury** ([R.I.P.](http://io9.com/5916175/rip-ray-bradbury-author-of-fahrenheit-451-and-the-martian-chronicles))? (On Martian Chronicles, for example?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't anything based directly on that source material. [Gurps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurps) is a system that is very moldable (name literally means Generic universal roleplaying system) and is great for that, but can also be overwheming at times. [Gamma World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_World) has a post-apocalyptic  setting but the tone is definitely off I think for something like the Martian Chronicles. [Traveller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveller_%28game%29) also could be a fit though its always reminded me most strongly of Asimov's foundation series.